# Create an object dynamically from a .each() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create dynamically a simple object like this one

```
var markers = {
    0 : { "group":1, "icon":"plus" },
    1 : { "group":2, "icon":"cross" },
    2 : { "group":2, "icon":"minus" },
};
```

...from a jquery loop .each() to get data from the Dom. I tried this without success:

```
var markers = {};
$('.markers').each(function(i) {
    let group = { group: $(this).data("group") };
    let icon = { icon: $(this).data("icon") };
    let obj = {group, icon};
    markers[i] = {arr};
});
```

I come from php and I still don't understand multidimensional array in javascript (or objects in that case). Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Close, but `arr` should be `obj`. Additionally... an array would be better for storing this type of data, at which point you could swap from .each to .map, because .map returns an array. (check the .map docs first for an example)

Comment: You're talking about multidimensional Arrays `[[]]`, which in the context of object `{0: []}` makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is correct, but to put them both into `obj`, you would need to do `let obj = {group: group.group, icon: icon.icon}`. I know, weird right? Well, the thing is, the key of the object is interpreted as it is - in other words you can't assign it a variable value, unless you use square bracket indexing (such as what you did with `markers[i]` - since it was in square brackets, `i` was interpreted as a variable instead of a key, and its value became the key). For the other part, you declared a variable group and assigned it the object `{group: $(this).data("group")}`, so to set the data, you would need to say `group.group` - the first `group` gets the object, the second `group` gets the data inside the object with the key of `group`.

```js
var markers = {};
$('.markers').each(function(i) {
  let obj = {
    group: $(this).data("group"),
    icon: $(this).data("icon")
  };
  markers[i] = obj;
});
console.log(markers)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="markers" data-group="1" data-icon="icon1">a</div>
<div class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="icon2">b</div>
<div class="markers" data-group="3" data-icon="icon3">c</div>
```

However, I would recommend that you use an array, since you can still refer to it as [1], [2], etc., it is a simpler data structure, and it allows you to iterate through them easily in cases you might need to do so:

```js
var markers = [];
$('.markers').each(function(i) {
  let obj = {
    group: $(this).data("group"),
    icon: $(this).data("icon")
  };
  markers.push(obj);
});
console.log(markers)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="markers" data-group="1" data-icon="icon1">a</div>
<div class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="icon2">b</div>
<div class="markers" data-group="3" data-icon="icon3">c</div>
```

Comment: I see that this was downvoted, and I was wondering why - the code seems to work for me, did I miss something?

Comment: I think it's my post which is downvoted... I don't understand why... It's a simple question and it's my fist post. :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a result as **Object** (as you stated) with indexed (`0, 1, 2, ...`) properties (which is quite odd) than you could:

```js
const markers = [...document.querySelectorAll(".markers")].reduce((ob, el, i) => {
  ob[i] = el.dataset;
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(markers);
```

```html
<i class="markers" data-group="1" data-icon="plus">+</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="cross">x</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="minus">-</i>
```

Since it's odd to have an Object with incremental numeric properties - and since Arrays are best suited for that job:

```js
const markers = [...document.querySelectorAll(".markers")].reduce((ar, el) => {
  ar.push(el.dataset);
  return ar;
}, []);

console.log(markers);
console.log(markers[0]); // {"group": "1", "icon": "plus"}
```

```html
<i class="markers" data-group="1" data-icon="plus">+</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="cross">x</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="minus">-</i>
```

If instead you want to **group by the marker's** `group` dataset than:

```js
const markers = [...document.querySelectorAll(".markers")].reduce((ob, el, i) => {
  if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(el.dataset.group)) ob[el.dataset.group] = [];
  ob[el.dataset.group].push(el.dataset);
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(markers);
```

```html
<i class="markers" data-group="1" data-icon="plus">+</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="cross">x</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="minus">-</i>
```

giving back this Object as result, where the property matches the group ID:

```js
{
  "1": [
    {
      "group": "1",
      "icon": "plus"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "group": "2",
      "icon": "cross"
    },
    {
      "group": "2",
      "icon": "minus"
    }
  ]
}
```

if you want to do the latest one the jQuery way (less performant):

```js
const markers = $(".markers").get().reduce(function(ob, el, i) {
  const d = $(el).data();
  if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(d.group)) ob[d.group] = [];
  ob[d.group].push(d);
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(markers);
```

```html
<i class="markers" data-group="1" data-icon="plus">+</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="cross">x</i>
<i class="markers" data-group="2" data-icon="minus">-</i>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon that's pretty much basic JS knowledge, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I don't agree with @Endothermic_Dragon: to me this is the most obvious way of doing what OP had in mind. It is _exactly_ what I would have posted too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your very much for all answers ! :-))))
One of your solutions worked for me. But by curiosity...

@Roko C. Buljan : You said to me it's quite odd to want a result as Object with indexed (0, 1, 2, ...) properties...

For me, it's like an associative array in php :

```
$markers = array(
    ['group'=>1,'name'=>'plus'],
    ['group'=>2,'name'=>'cross'],
    ['group'=>2,'name'=>'minus']
);
```

If I don't need to name my index for making a loop for...in ? or do I ?

In php, there are associative arrays and there are not in javascript. I've read that we have to use Objects instead... But what if we just need to make simply a loop with these datas :

```
for(marker in markers){
let group = markers[marker].group;
let name = markers[marker].name;
//make things...
}
```

well... I could just use jquery each time I need, instead storing this in vars at the beginning. But it is the good way of doing this ?